# What's the preferred method in the community for having python 2.x and 3.x in the same codebase?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am starting a project in Python 3.x, (I'm quite new to Python) and there exists the possibility that I will need to use say Thrift or any other library that is not yet ported to Python 3.x.

I don't mind about devoting some (substantial) amount of time to convert an external library to Python 3.x if with that others can benefit from that, but I'm curious if there's any preferred way in the Open Source community to deal with this problem.

I have been reading here and there in the python.org site and in some other websites, but I haven't found anything conclusive.  The only thing that I found is that this is a chicken-and-egg problem.

It's out of the question (unless there's no other option) that I ship a dump of a library with my own modifications just to make it 3.x compliant.

Should I...

1. prepare all the code with __future imports and change here and there appropriately and leave it ready to work with both 2.x and 3.x?  Am I going to find any problem with this, other than the natural resistance of upstream to integrate such amount of changes?
2. create another branch of the code?  That, to me, should be quite useless, as nobody will maintain that branch except me, probably, and it's a huge duplication effort.
3. use some type of wrapper that I am not aware of to use those libraries as-is (like using some intermediate bindings in another language) and just create the glue in my code?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you ask the authors of the package what their strategy is?  When they plan to support 3 and how you can help them?  What did they say?

Comment: Did you ask the authors of the package (Thrift) what their strategy is?

Comment: It seems that I work in the same place as the main Python Thrift developer. :-)  I'll drop him a note.
On a side note, S.Lott, thanks for your encouragement and pushing me to it. :-)

Comment: What's important here is there is no "community" position. That implies central planning.  This is anarchy (technically) and there are only a lot of individuals.  Asking about a "community position" is essentially impossible.  Therefore, the question -- as asked -- is unanswerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various strategies you can use, and which is best depends on several things, like what you are porting, how complex it is and how much of Pythons internals it uses.Basically, if you want to support both Python 2 and Python 3 at one time, run 2to3 on your code, and see how much it changes. If the changes are mostly such things that you can solve with `__future__` imports, then porting to Python 3 and the reintroducing Python 2 compatibility may be a feasible way forward.
(For an in-depth look at this, see my [Migration strategies](http://python3porting.com/strategies.html) page.)

If the changes are major, you are probably better off using 2to3 to support Python 3. This is made easier if you can use Distribute for packaging your project.

In both cases you may have use of [six](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six).

See also [my talk on the subject](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2011-porting-to-python-3-4895521).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest supporting Python 2.x and Python 3.x simultaneously from the same code base, using [tox](http://codespeak.net/tox/). Check out the [Supporting All Versions of Python All The Time With Tox](http://blip.tv/file/4879179)  talk from Pycon 2011.

Comment: Nice and sweet, thanks!  The blog post about Mock also seems to be a nice starting point about how to deal with several major Python version at the same time.

Comment: Tox helps with testing, though, it doesn't actually help with the code. :-)

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: That's true. Hopefully 2to3 (`use_2to3 = True` in setup.py) does most of the work for you :-)

Comment: Sure, but use_2to3 is a part of Distribute. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The approach I've been using is to maintain the code in version 2 format, use the 2to3 converter, and test the output in version 3. If there are errors with the generated version 3 code, I work with the version 2 code to get a better conversion until it works. The Python wiki has some good advice on this: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3

[PEP 3000](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3000/#compatibility-and-transition) also has some good advice on maintaining a dual-version codebase.

When your library is finally 3.x-ready, (maybe doing it yourself) then you have a 3.x codebase ready to go.

Comment: 3.0 is unsupported. Say 3.x instead. Or 3.1. Or just 3.

Answer (score 2):

I Can't talk for the community but these `from __future__ import ...` don't work for all python versions or aren't reliable on some cases.

`print_function` and `unicode_literals` were added on Python2.6, `with_statement` on Python2.5 and the others on Python2.2

So, if you want to support 2.6 or later, you're fine. If you still need to support 2.5 or, even worst, 2.4, you will need another approach.

Using `from __future__ import unicode_literals` won't work properly because Python2 let you do conversion from byte to unicode without encoding while Python3 don't. Also, calling `str` or `bytes` has different arguments.

The difference of treatment on strings seems to be the main problem to make a program compatible with both Python2 and Python3.

Comment: All right, this is what I wanted.  So it will be a matter of looking in a per-project basis to see if they are supporting old Python versions and thus using `__future__` statements or not.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/pyporting.html is the source for the most up-to-date advice from the CPython core devs (although it sounds like you have already looked at that).

Comment: Many thanks, it seems that it changed since the last time I took a look.  Anyway I wanted advice more on how people is reacting than the supposed way to go, but I have lots of material on both aspects.